# SSRS Tablix header not repeating

Tags: reporting-services, header, ssrs-tablix

I'm working on SSRS tablix and when I have data more than one page, my tablix header is not repeating on the next page.

I set RepeatOnNewPage = True and KeepWithGroup = After

Here is the screenshot. In the below report, the 3rd column (Sales Team) has more data and it went to the 2nd page. But the header not showing on the second page. Only blank row appearing.

**Note:** There is no default group as I've put another table in the column to filter data based on value. Is that causing issues?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under the column Groups, click on the Advanced Mode

[image]

This will then show some static elements under the Row Group.

Select each static element and ensure RepeatonNewPage property is set to true. Note, this needs to be done on all the static elements under the column group.. else it will not run

[image]

Comment: Hi Harry Thanks for your response. Yes, I did the same. It is working when there is less number of records. When there are more records in one cell and if it is extending to next page, it is failing.